# keychain certificate

Tags: ios, keychain

i am creating a new CSR (Certificate Signing Request) using the Keychain Access tool:

Certificate Assistant -> Request a certificate from a certificate authority...
In the certificate information I fill in my email address and name, selecting the "Save to disk" option.
I save the CSR to the desktop
The wizard completes successfully, but no file is saved to disk!
I've done this before, but this time it just isn't working. I tried restarting the Keychain tool, restarting the computer ....but could n't find anything...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

After you created the certificate in the Keychain Access tool you can export it to disk.

Select the appropriate keychain, then select the created certificate you would like to export and chose File - > Export Items on the main menu. After that follow the steps of the export wizard.

You can choose the type of the file you would like to export the certificate to like .cert or .p12.